# Java Justify text in string to far left/start and far right/end and leave space in the middle

Tags: java, string, char, justify

I am having a string in java that i am printing and has title and amount for example below

```
Rice Ksh 150
Cooking Oil Ksh 200
Skinless White Meat Ksh 450
Honey Ksh 270
Cottage Cheese Ksh 539
```

What i would like to achieve when i print is something like this below

```
Rice                Ksh 150
Cooking Oil         Ksh 200
Skinless White Meat Ksh 450
Honey               Ksh 270
Cottage Cheese      Ksh 539
```

Below is what i have tried but its not working is there another function that i can use to make the output justified where title of the items is far left/start and amount is far right/end

```
for (Receipt receipt : receiptList) {


        String output = "";

        String itemAmount = String.format("%s %s %s", receipt.getItem(),
                    "Ksh", receipt.getAmount());

        for (int i = 0; i < itemAmount.length(); i++){
            char c = itemAmount.charAt(i);
            if (c==' '){
                output += " ";
            }else {
                output += "" + c;
            }
        }

        // print output here

}
```

Comment: you can find max Length for receipt. And use it to calculate spaces for others.

Comment: @MasterYi do you have sample code

Comment: What’s the point of this inefficient copying loop? Afterwards, `output` contain exactly the same as `itemAmount`. When you use `String.format` anyway, let it do its job, like `String output = String.format("%-20s Ksh%5s", receipt.getItem(), receipt.getAmount());`. When your “print output here” means printing to the console/resp. stdout, you can just use `System.out.printf("%-20s Ksh%5s%n", receipt.getItem(), receipt.getAmount());` to format and print in one go.

Comment: @Holger i am printing using a hard copy printer thats why i wanted them to be arranged

Comment: I never asked you why you want to format the output. I asked why you added an entirely pointless copying loop which has no effect at all.

Comment: that one was supposed to justify the string text in all the lines to be the same line 1, 2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

I would use `System.out.printf` and specify the width of each column.

Example:

```
String[] item = {"Rice", "Cooking Oil", "Skinless White Meat", "Honey", "Cottage Cheese"};
int[] amount = {150,200,450,270,539};
        
for(int i=0; i<item.length; i++)
  System.out.printf("%-20s%4s%4d\n", item[i],"Ksh", amount[i]);
```

Output:

```
Rice                 Ksh 150
Cooking Oil          Ksh 200
Skinless White Meat  Ksh 450
Honey                Ksh 270
Cottage Cheese       Ksh 539
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Receipt> receiptList = asList(
            new Receipt("Rice Ksh", 150),
            new Receipt("Skinless White Meat Ksh", 150),
            new Receipt("Cottage Cheese Ksh", 150));
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (Receipt receipt : receiptList) {
        if(receipt.getItem().length()>maxSize)
            maxSize = receipt.getItem().length();
    }
    for (Receipt receipt : receiptList) {
        int spaces = maxSize+1 - receipt.item.length();
        String s = String.format("%1$"+spaces+"s", "");
        System.out.println(receipt.item.substring(0,receipt.item.length()-3) + s + " KSH " + receipt.amount );
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Rice                  KSH 150
Skinless White Meat   KSH 150
Cottage Cheese        KSH 150
```

performance log(n).

Comment: this one is trimming items title especially if they are long